# How can I calculate Index of Coincidence of Vigenère cipher?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, discrete-mathematics, cryptography

I have computed the letter frequency of the cipher text. However, I don't know how to apply Friedman Test to Vigenère cipher. I couldn't calculate the Index of Coincidence. Does anyone can help to me ?

Letters' frequencies :

$f_{0} = 0.059 \qquad f_{14} = 0.031 \\
f_{1} =0.055 \qquad f_{15} = 0.064 \\
f_{2} = 0.030 \qquad f_{16} = 0.029 \\
f_{3} = 0.018 \qquad f_{17} = 0.026 \\
f_{4} = 0.029 \qquad f_{18} = 0.027 \\
f_{5} = 0.040 \qquad f_{19} = 0.042 \\
f_{6} = 0.070 \qquad f_{20} = 0.046 \\
f_{7} = 0.030 \qquad f_{21} = 0.046 \\
f_{8} = 0.032 \qquad f_{22} = 0.017 \\
f_{9} = 0.023 \qquad f_{23} = 0.027 \\
f_{10} = 0.046 \qquad f_{24} = 0.036 \\
f_{11} = 0.059 \qquad f_{25} = 0.032 \\
f_{12} = 0.046 \\
f_{13} = 0.039 $

By using these frequencies, how can I calculate Index of Coincidence ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to these relative frequencies, you need the actual numerical frequencies of the individual letters. If $n_k$ is the actual number of instances of letter $k$, and $n$ is the total number of letters, for each letter you need the quantity

$$\frac{n_k}n\cdot\frac{n_k-1}{n-1}=f_k\cdot\frac{n_k-1}{n-1}\;.$$

The index of coincidence is then

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbf{IC}&=26\left(f_k\cdot\frac{n_1-1}{n-1}+f_2\cdot\frac{n_k-1}{n-1}+\ldots+f_k\cdot\frac{n_{26}-1}{n-1}\right)\\
&=\frac{26}{n(n-1)}\Big(n_1(n_1-1)+n_2(n_2-1)+\ldots+n_{26}(n_{26}-1)\Big)\;.
\end{align*}$$

The [Wikipedia description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_coincidence) of it is short but fairly readable.

Note that the factor of $26$ (which is actually the number of different letters, so it could be different for different languages) is often omitted, as it is at [this more detailed explanation](http://practicalcryptography.com/cryptanalysis/text-characterisation/index-coincidence/).

Comment: @Rinzler: You’re very welcome!